# Delete A specific list box item which is bind to xml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listboxitem

i have a listbox which is bound to an xml file.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Hold="teacher_detail_Hold" Margin="0,12,0,12">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Teacher}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="subjectName" Text="{Binding Subject}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Session}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="delete" Click="delete_record"/>
 </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

here is my data class

```
public class TimeTable
    {
        string teacher;
        string subject;
        string session;
        string group;
        string time;

        //Teacher Property
        public string Teacher
        {
            get { return teacher; }
            set { teacher = value; }
        }
        //Subject Property
        public string Subject
        {
            get { return subject; }
            set { subject = value; }
        }
        //Session Propert
        public string Session
        {
            get { return session; }
            set { session = value; }
        }
        //Group Property
        public string Group
        {
            get { return group; }
            set { group = value; }
        }
        //Time Property
        public string Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set { time = value; }
        }
    }
```

And this is the xml file i am using.

```
<Day id="Monday">
    <subject sbjname="Software Testing" session="2010" group="Alpha" teacher="Tasawar Khan" classroom="Class Room 1" time="8:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
<Day id="Tuesday">
    <subject sbjname="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>

  </Day>
```

I want to delete an entry on pressing delete button. I want to delete the data on the basis of **sbjname** attribute. 
here is the deletebutton click method

```
private void delete_record(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                    }
```

**I know how to delete from xml file. but i don't know how to get the subject name from the item selected in listbox.**

Comment: Show some binding code, listbox.ItemsSource=???

Answer (score 0):

```
YourDataClass item = listBox.SelectedItem as YourDataClass ; 
YourdataList.Remove(item);
```

Comment: what is YourdataList here.. I have to remove the data from xml file.